# Limiting access in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

Let's say I have `users` and users can see other users but there are also `admins` and they can see some properties that regular users not supposed to see.

How do I implement it in GraphQL?

Should I create different root calls `users` for regular users and `usersForAdmins` for admins and restrict access to that root call?

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check users privileges in resolvers and  return different data

Comment: But the schema is not dynamic. Do you mean I should set not available fields to `null`?
I thought about it but in some cases I would like not to show even some fields names.

Comment: In schema you should mark fileds for admins without `!`(exclamation mark), you can return them only if user admin. For normal users - do not return them

Comment: I will be able to hide a value, but structure will be exposed.
My point is that what kind information I store in my database (fields names, even without values) - is also secret information.
Or I am missing something? Thanks.

Comment: In schema: `User: { nonSecret: String!, Secret: String }`. If non-admin user makes request, you return from resolver only field `nonSecret`. If user is admin, when you return from the same resolver both field, `nonSecret` and `Secret`.

Comment: Right, but that does not hide schema from introspection queries.

Comment: There is a way to disable introspection with `validation rules` but still client can guess by `bruteforcing` field names. Yes, non-admin client will see only `null` but he will know that there is such field in schema.

Comment: If your concern is that the schema itself leaks sensitive information, you should have two version of the schema, a public one (for regular people) and a private one for staff members.

Comment: Agree with Andrew